# Clarification of relationship between CORS and CSRF

Tags: csrf, cors

## To summarize:

- **CSRF** is an attack where a page in a different window/tab of the browser
  sends nonconsensual request to an authenticated web app, that can **typically
  be prevented** from server-side by checking the Referer, Origin header of the
  request or including anti-CSRF token in request header or body.
- **CORS** is variously defined in different sources, that might roughly be
  summarized as: a mechanism that host-of-origin-B indicates to the browser
  how or whether a host-of-origin-A content should access its resources.

## Cross-origin-related attacks and party responsible for defence

1. Nonconsensual "state-changing" requests: **The server**.

Be it a treacherous form submission, XHR/fetch request from a
"second-origin" page, the server need to recognize and reject them.

2. Cross-origin data (credential, privacy) leaking: **The browser**.

Be it a media tag (img, video, audio), XHR/fetch request, the browser must
isolate those data from the access of "second-origin" pages.

3. Q1: anythine else?

## Purpose of CORS in cross-origin settings

To let browsers make informed decisions on how:

1. To make concensual "state-changing" possible cross-origin.

Q2: Is there an real-world example of concensual cross-origin
"state-changing" *user action*?

2. To allow "creative" ways of collecting and using of digital assets hosted
   at "second-origin" host(s) by the script.

## Misc.

Q3: CORS doesn't help browser protect users from malicious digital asset hosts
determined to steal data from users? But honest origin servers can prevent them
from submitting CSRF requests?

Comment: W3C has an [article for developers](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-cors-for-developers/) on this that's probably less confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit of a rambling question, so bit of a rambling answer also.

CSRF can also be defended by including a custom header on XHR requests, and with same site cookies.

CORS is not variously defined; it is a W3C [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/). What sometimes causes confusion is that CORS is not really a security mechanism.

Cross-origin data leaking is an area of [active research](https://portswigger.net/daily-swig/new-xs-leak-techniques-reveal-fresh-ways-to-expose-user-information) and requires defences both built-in to the browser, and in both server-side and client-side application code.

Q1) The main other cross-origin attack is cross-site scripting. Defences needed in both server-side and client-side application code. Clickjacking is another one. There are probably some more although I can't think just now.

Q2) I've found most uses of CORS are for reads. Some REST APIs have permissive CORS settings but require a security token in requests. This lets third-party domains access the API, once the user has authorized them, e.g using OAuth.

Q3) That's right, CORS is not a security mechanism and doesn't in itself defend against anything. It does sometimes stop people using insecure alternatives like JSONP so it can help security.